# Is sum of two square summable sequences is again square summable?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove the set $W=\{(a_n) | \sum a_n^2 <∞\}$ is subspace of vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^∞$ (vector space of all sequences of real numbers)

For this, clearly as $0^2+ 0^2+...=0 <∞$
Hence (0) is in $W$.

Further, if $(a_n), (b_n) \in W$ then we have $\sum a_n^2<∞$ and $\sum b_n^2<∞$.

**How can I prove** $\sum (a_n+b_n)^2<∞$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\sum x_n^2$ and $\sum y_n^2$ converge, what does $\sum (x_n + y_n)^2$ do?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309739/sum-x-n2-and-sum-y-n2-converge-what-does-sum-x-n-y-n2-do) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20(a_n%2Bb_n)%5E2%24&p=1)

Comment: @Martin R  Sir thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$(a_n+b_n)^2 \leq 2 (a_n^2+b_n^2)$$